# Cannot get Boolean from VB.NET project in C# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've created a project in VB.NET that uses a dll in C#. I want to get a boolean variable from My.settings in the VB.NET project to the C# project. Is it possible ?

Here's the C# code i want :

```cs
if (//the code to get My.settings)
{
    tv.ExpandAll();
}
```

Here's My self-made code (doesn't work) :

```cs
if ((string)(Variables.GetVar("AutoExpand")) == "True") //Variables is another DLL i made to store temp variables
{
    tv.ExpandAll();
}
```

Here's the Variables DLL code :

```vb
Public Class Variables

    Shared ActiveJSON As String
    Shared AutoExpand As String

    Shared Function SetVar(ByVal var As String, ByVal value As String)
        If var = "ActiveJSON" Then
            ActiveJSON = value
            Return True
            Exit Function
        End If
        If var = "AutoExpand" Then
            AutoExpand = var
            Return True
            Exit Function
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Shared Function GetVar(ByVal var As String)
        If var = "ActiveJSON" Then
            Return ActiveJSON
            Exit Function
        End If
        If var = "AutoExpand" Then
            Return AutoExpand
            Exit Function
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You need to show the code that shows how `Variables` is defined. Not just how it's used.

Comment: Don't use 'String' when you should be using 'Boolean' in VB - you have this continual exchange of strings and booleans which just adds to the confusion. Also, why would you have 'Exit Function' immediately after a 'Return'?

Answer (score 3):

The language doesn't matter. A library cannot get settings from an application using `My.Settings` in VB or `Properties.Settings.Default` in C#. If a library needs to read settings from an application then you should use the `appSettings` section of the config file and then any library loaded by the application can use the `Configuration` class to read those values.

For example, if you included this in your App.config or Web.config file:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="SettingName" value="SettingValue" />
</appSettings>
```

then you can do this in library:

```cs
var settingValue = System.Configuration.Configuration.AppSettings["SettingName"];
```

Note that your `My.Settings` values are also stored in the config file so you can access them but there's no dedicated mechanism via the `Configuration` class so it is more laborious. Basically, those settings are not intended to be used by libraries.